# VB.NET & SQL Server database : adding record from textbox

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, vb.net

I am trying to make a highscore table that will take the users name from textbox and grab the score from a label on another form and store them into a database called highscores. I can get the connection to work but I can't figure out how to add the records I need added and display them in the datagrid view.

```
    Private MyDatAdp As New SqlDataAdapter
    Private MyCmdBld As New SqlCommandBuilder
    Private MyDataTbl As New DataTable
    Private MyCn As New SqlConnection
    Private MyRowPosition As Integer = 0

    Private Sub highscore_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        MyCn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(localDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Scores.mdf;integrated security = true;Connect Timeout = 30"
        MyCn.Open()

        MyDatAdp = New SqlDataAdapter("Select* from HighScores", MyCn)
        MyCmdBld = New SqlCommandBuilder(MyDatAdp)
        MyDatAdp.Fill(MyDataTbl)

        Dim MyDataRow As DataRow = MyDataTbl.Rows(1)
        Dim MyDataRow2 As DataRow = MyDataTbl.Rows(2)

        Dim Name As String
        Dim Score As String
        Name = MyDataRow("Name")
        Score = MyDataRow2("Score")
        NameBox.Text = Name.ToString
        Math.Score.Text = Score.ToString
        Me.showRecords()

    End Sub

    Private Sub showRecords()

        If MyDataTbl.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            NameBox.Text = ""
            Math.Score.Text = ""
            Exit Sub
        End If

        NameBox.Text = MyDataTbl.Rows(MyRowPosition)("Name").ToString
        Math.Score.Text = MyDataTbl.Rows(MyRowPosition)("Score").ToString

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: A question without a question mark is not a question.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting any errors it just won't update the records. I basically need to know what code is to make it save a record from a text box called nameBox.Text and how to make it save a record from  a label called score.Text. I have been at it for 3 days now and can't seem to figure out the code to make it add records.

Comment: 3 days and you haven't implemented any kind of INSERT/UPDATE SQL code yet? I think you should read some tutorials on SQL first.

Comment: I got the datagridview working and got the name to save from the text box.  using      Try
            Me.Validate()
            Me.HighScoresBindingSource.EndEdit()
            Me.HighScoresTableAdapter.Update(Me.ScoresDataSet.HighScores)
            MsgBox("Update successful")

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Update failed")
        End Try       Now I need help with getting the label that is on another form that the score is saved in to save to the database. Can anyone help me figure out how to do this?